# How does React Native live reloads native components?

Tags: react-native

I was watching a video and the speaker said that react uses native iOS components. I am not sure how is this possible without compiling the app. Or is it that the live reload feature is only for web views?, but he also said that everything is mapped to native views

Can someone please clarify this?

[Link to the talk](http://jlongster.com/Why-React-Native-is-Different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native is split into native code, which actually creates the native components, and JavaScript, which is run in the JavaScript Core environment. RN also has a feature called the React Native bridge, which allows JavaScript to talk to Objective C code. Because JavaScript is not a compiled language, the scripts used in your app (all stored in a single `.jsbundle` file) can be swapped at any time. At run time the JavaScript is interpreted and talks to Objective C, telling it what native components it needs created.